# How can I lock a table in PHPMyAdmin so it can't be modified?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to lock a certain table (called `gmd_settings`) so it can't be modified anymore, but my lack of experience with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin plagues me. I need it explained to me how I would do this in simple terms, to someone that doesn't manage MySQL databases for a living.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i lock tables in MySQL or phpmyadmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996219/how-can-i-lock-tables-in-mysql-or-phpmyadmin)

Comment: I've seen that particular question and it doesn't answer, in simple terms, how I can achieve what I'm looking for. I've already went over that article and the documentation that was linked and it doesn't help me figure out what I need to do in order to do this with PHPMyAdmin or even what to do to get it right. Additionally, the reasoning for his question is a bit different than mine.

Comment: Then you might want to add that to your question Joseph. Right now, just with the title, it looks like exactly the same thing. If you don't include that other answer and why it doesn't apply to your case, that will be seen as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you should set up proper permissions. MySQL allows you to set permissions not only on a database and table level, but also on individual columns. If you create a new user (or edit the user you're using for this project) and set the permissions you desire, you can limit the user's ability to edit the `gmd_settings` table. Make sure you don't lock yourself out and I suggest that you make sure you understand what's happening rather than just copying the steps I outline. With that being said, here's what I would do:

Click on the Users tab and the Edit Privileges for the user you wish to edit (or Add a new user).

Near the top, look for the second level of tabs where you can select "Database":
[image: Database tab]

Then select your database from the list and click Go:
[image: Database selector]

Next, from the second level of tabs again click on "Table"

Now you have to add permissions for each table. From the dropdown select each table in turn and grant the proper set of permissions. For `gmd_settings`, that might be only SELECT, for the rest you'll probably at least also need INSERT and UPDATE. Again, these will depend on your configuration and specific needs; you should have some understanding of what you're doing here.

[image: Select-only privileges]

[image: Select, Insert, and Update privileges]
Hopefully that will get you where you want to be.